# How can I refer to self during initialization when using IBOutlets for UIViews?

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I have this custom UITableViewCell class backing my cells in a table view (I learned this approach from a talk by Andy Matuschak who worked at Apple on the UIKit team).

In the project I'm trying to apply this to now, I'm having a problem initializing the class because of a couple of `@IBOutlets` that are linked to `UIView` elements that won't ever have values like the `UILabel`s get upon initialization:

```
class PublicationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var publicationTitle: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var authorName: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var pubTypeBadgeView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pubTypeBadge: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var topHighlightGradientStackView: UIStackView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomBorder: UIView!

  struct ViewData {
    let publicationTitle: UILabel
    let authorName: UILabel
    let pubTypeBadge: UILabel
  }

  var viewData: ViewData! {
    didSet {
      publicationTitle = viewData.publicationTitle
      authorName = viewData.authorName
      pubTypeBadge = viewData.pubTypeBadge
    }

  // I have @IBOutlets linked to the views so I can do this:
  override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    if isSelected || isHighlighted {
      topHighlightGradientStackView.isHidden = true
      bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrey1
    } else {
      topHighlightGradientStackView.isHidden = false
    }
  }
}

extension PublicationTableViewCell.ViewData {
  init(with publication: PublicationModel) {

    // Xcode complains here about referring to the properties 
    // on the left before all stored properties are initialized

    publicationTitle.text = publication.title
    authorName.text = publication.formattedAuthor.name
    pubTypeBadge.attributedText = publication.pubTypeBadge
  }
}
```

I then initialize it in `cellForRow` by passing in a publication like this:

```
cell.viewData = PublicationTableViewCell.ViewData(with: publication)
```

Xcode is complaining that I'm using `self` in `init(with publication: PublicationModel)` before all stored properties are initialized which I understand, but I can't figure out how to fix.

If these weren't `UIView` properties I might make them optional or computed properties perhaps, but because these are `IBOutlet`s, I think they need to be implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Is there some other way I can get this to work?

Comment: Start with changing the values of `struct ViewData` to be `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
struct ViewData {
   let publicationTitle: String
   let authorName: String
   let pubTypeBadge: NSAttributedString
}
```

Then simply:

```
extension PublicationTableViewCell.ViewData {
  init(with publication: PublicationModel) 
    publicationTitle = publication.title
    authorName = publication.formattedAuthor.name
    pubTypeBadge = publication.pubTypeBadge
  }
}
```

It's a data model, it shouldn't hold *views*, it should hold only *data*.

Then:

```
var viewData: ViewData! {
    didSet {
       publicationTitle.text = viewData.publicationTitle
       authorName.text = viewData.authorName
       pubTypeBadge.attributedString = viewData.pubTypeBadge
   }
}
```

However, I think it would be simpler if you just passed `PublicationModel` as your cell data. There is no reason to convert it to another `struct`.

```
var viewData: PublicationModel! {
    didSet {
       publicationTitle.text = viewData.publicationTitle
       authorName.text = viewData.authorName
       pubTypeBadge.attributedString = viewData.pubTypeBadge
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sulthan. I don't disagree with you about just passing `PublicationModel`. I'll have to watch the presentation by Andy again, but I believe the use of the `struct` was about making it an immutable object.